# JavaScript If Else errors

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I have this little problem with my `if` `else` structure. When I put in a correct star for example "Vega", the costellation shows me that it is false ("Error") while it needs to show me "Lyra".

My code is below:

```js
var stars = ["Polaris", "Aldebaran", "Deneb", "Vega", "Altair", "Dubhe", "Regulus"];
var costellations = ["Ursu Minor", "Taurus", "Cygnus", "Lyra", "Aquila", "Ursa Major","Leo"];
function Arrays() {
    for (n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {
        if (test.inputStars.value == stars[n]) {
            test.inputCostellations.value = costellations[n];
        }else{ 
          test.inputCostellations.value = "Error"; 
        }
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Array structures</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form name = "test">
          <input type = "text" name = "inputStars">
          <input type = "button" onclick ="Arrays()" value = "Find costellation">
          <input type = "text" name = "inputCostellations">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please bring the code into the question so people can help.

Comment: Post the code in the question as text. See [mcve].

Comment: I am sorry everyone, i am new here at Stack Overflow but im doing my best to get used to the environment. I just posted the code in my Question.

Comment: @Taplar Wow, I had no idea. Doesn't seem like a very good idea though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, when the `for` loop is running, the `test.inputConstellations.value` will be overridden, even if previously the program found a match. The solution is the `break`:

```
if(test.inputStars.value==stars[n]){
    test.inputConstellations.value=constellations[n]
    break
}else{
    test.inputCostellations.value = "Error"
}
```

```js
var stars = ["Polaris", "Aldebaran", "Deneb", "Vega", "Altair", "Dubhe", "Regulus"];
var costellations = ["Ursu Minor", "Taurus", "Cygnus", "Lyra", "Aquila", "Ursa Major","Leo"];
function Arrays() {
    for (n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {
        if (test.inputStars.value == stars[n]) {
            test.inputCostellations.value = costellations[n];
            break
        }else{ 
          test.inputCostellations.value = "Error"; 
        }
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title> Array structures</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form name = "test">
          <input type = "text" name = "inputStars">
          <input type = "button" onclick ="Arrays()" value = "Find costellation">
          <input type = "text" name = "inputCostellations">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value for variable and overwrite when true:

```
var stars = ["Polaris", "Aldebaran", "Deneb", "Vega", "Altair", "Dubhe", "Regulus"];
var costellations = ["Ursu Minor", "Taurus", "Cygnus", "Lyra", "Aquila", "Ursa Major","Leo"];

function Arrays() {

    test.inputCostellations.value = "Error"; 
    for (n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {
        if (test.inputStars.value == stars[n]) {
            test.inputCostellations.value = costellations[n];
        }
    }           
}
```

And use a break:

```
var stars = ["Polaris", "Aldebaran", "Deneb", "Vega", "Altair", "Dubhe", "Regulus"];
var costellations = ["Ursu Minor", "Taurus", "Cygnus", "Lyra", "Aquila", "Ursa Major","Leo"];

function Arrays() {

    test.inputCostellations.value = "Error"; 
    for (n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {
        if (test.inputStars.value == stars[n]) {
            test.inputCostellations.value = costellations[n];
            break;
        }
    }           
}
```